# Obtain page title in MVC global

Tags: model-view-controller

I am just beginning to move from ASPX C# web forms to MVC Razor.
What I am trying to do is use the MVC global much as I did in master page code behind.
The objective is to define page title and then assign a specific image to the _Layout.cshtml.

In the aspx web pages master code behind I used Case (switch)statement like this:

```
string Title = PageTitle;
switch (Title)
{
  case "Quality":
  imgPix.ImageUrl = "images.picureA.gif";
  break;

  case "Services":
  imgPix.imageUrl = "images.pictureB.gif":
  break;

 -- and so on for 8 various pages --
}
```

This works very well to load images on Page_Load in the aspx web pages.
I want to do this in the MVC global if possible, any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Such a code must be in controllers. Then you just "send" imageUrl  variable to view and use it.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try.